# Raster in R: Create Zonal Count of specific cell values without reclassification

Tags: r, geospatial, raster

I would like to know if there is way to create `zonal statistics` for `RasterLayerObjects`, specifically the `count` of a given cell value (e.g. a land-use class) in R without having to reclassify the whole raster. The solution should be memory efficient in order to work on large raster files i.e. no extraction of the values into a matrix in R is desired.

Below an example of how I handle it until now. In this case I reclassify the original raster to hold only 1 for the value of interest and missings for all other values.

My proposed solution creates both, redundant data and additional processing steps to get me to my initial goal. I thought something like `zonal(r1[r1==6],r2,"count")` would work but obviously it does not (see below).

```
# generate reproducible Raster 
library("raster")

## RASTER 1 (e.g. land-use classes)
r1 <- raster( crs="+proj=utm +zone=31")
extent(r1) <- extent(0, 100, 0, 100)
res(r1) <- c(5, 5)
values(r1) <- sample(10, ncell(r1), replace=TRUE)
plot(r1)

## RASTER 2 (containing zones of interest)
r2 <- raster( crs="+proj=utm +zone=31")
extent(r2) <- extent(0, 100, 0, 100)
res(r2) <- c(5, 5)
values(r2) <- c(rep(1,100),rep(2,100),rep(3,100),rep(4,100))
plot(r2)

# (1) ZONAL STATISTICS
# a. how many cells per zone (independent of specific cell value)
zonal(r1,r2,"count")

# b. how many cells per zone of specific value 6
zonal(r1[r1==6],r2,"count")
# -> fails

# with reclassification
r1.reclass<-
  reclassify(r1,
             matrix(c(1,5,NA,
                    5.5,6.5,1, #class of interest 
                    6.5,10,NA),
                    ncol=3,
                    byrow = T),
             include.lowest=T # include the lowest value from the table.
           )
zonal(r1.reclass,r2,"count")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `raster::match`.

```
zonal(match(r1, 6),r2, "count")
```

As you can see from `plot(match(r1, 6))`, it only returns raster cells which hold the desired value(s). All other cells are `NA`.

`r1==6` as used in your try unfortunately returns a vector and therefore cannot be used in focal anymore.

Comment: exactly what I need. Thanks!!

Comment: I should mention that the raster package will create temporary files to do that calculation and they are massive. if your disk space fills up, use 
`options(rasterTmpDir='/some_external_drive')` to put the files temporarily on an external drive.

Comment: I should also mention that this approach is not really faster than the manual reclassification. Probably because the raster package is not very efficient when creating the tmp files. My tmp. rasters are of size 25GB vs. my manually reclassified binary raster that only consumes 100 MB...